# ToBe or not toBe

Tags: javascript, jasmine

How can I express the `or` condition with Jasmine, something like:

```
expect(element.css("display")).toBe("").or.toBe("block");
                                        ^^
```

Is it possible? I know about `not` but what about `or`?

Comment: That is indeed a question

Comment: You could write your own custom assertion:
https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers#writing-new-matchers

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13530749/3348022

Comment: @user3153169 you mean something like this will work: http://jsfiddle.net/4p3s3/ ?

Comment: something like that indeed

Answer (score 1):

Tried to go `jasmine.addMatchers` way: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Matchers#writing-new-matchers
and created [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/4p3s3/) , but it gives me an error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'jasmine.addMatchers')

And if i understand correctly from [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/issues/31) it is a bug related to versions of karma-runner and Jasmine..

So i'm using this workaround for now:

```
  var display = element.css("display");
  var flag = (display=="block" || display == "");
  expect(flag).toBeTruthy();
```