# How to assert an actual value with two different expected values

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm writing a protractor test which asserts a URL against two different browser URLs.

I tried using `toMatch` with a regular expression but I get an error.

Is it possible to assert an actual string value against 2 or more expected string values and see if it is equal to any of them?

```
expect(url1).toMatch(/this.url|www.google.com/);
```

Comment: May be you will find something in jasmine-matchers npm module

Comment: If you are  using jasmine, check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530365/jasmine-expect-logic-expect-a-or-b

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use `toContain()` which works for finding an item in an array.  So switch your assertion around because you want to pass it an array of URLs `[this.url, 'www.google.com']` and assert that it will contain `url1`.

`expect([this.url, 'www.google.com']).toContain(url1);`

Note: While this should work, personally I don't like to have my values on the receiving end of the assertion i.e. `toContain(url1)`, I would rather that be passed first `expect(url1)...`.  However, in the end it's still asserting actual vs expected values so not a huge deal in my opinion.

https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Comment: Thank you for the help. I got it work by using the other way some thing like this and it works..  ! 


   expect(this.currentURL).toContain((url1|| 'www.google.com'));